# Destroying micellar particles using electrolytes

Tags: aqueous-solution

I learnt that micellar particles formed by ionic detergents forms due to the negative charges of H2O molecules are facing the solution, hence micellar particles repel each other.

[image]

I also learnt that micellar particles are destroyed upon the addition of an electrolyte, but I would like to know how.

My attempt: when aqueous cation and anion forms (from electrolyte), it means a lot of H2O molecules are 'consumed' to surround those ions. Therefore, fewer H2O molecules will surround the micellar particles, hence they will aggregate together (hydrophobic interaction?) and form suspensions.

I know my attempt has flaws e.g. when fewer H2O molecules surround the micellar particles, those Na+ are still present on the surface hence still repel each other, so I may be wrong.

I would like to know the real rationale behind it, thank you.

Comment: "Colloid" encompasses a great number of possible things. It would help if you narrowed your question to something more specific, say "micellar particles formed by ionic detergents" which your figure suggests is in question.

Comment: @BuckThorn Modified. Thanks for the suggestion